# Spyder won't even run the python file at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

When I click the green run button nothing happens at all. How can I fix this?

[image: Screenshot of my desktop]

Answer (score 1):

The program *is* running. You have three calls to `input`, and each call will wait for you to enter some text then press the `enter` on your keyboard before it will continue.

Click in the console (`Console 1/A`), and type a number next to `In [1]:` and press enter, three times.